# How to Prevent form submitting using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

Actually in jsp page i'm using spring tags and jquery code..
Hear is my code..

```
    <form:form action="process">

        <p class="forgot">
            <a href="login/forgotPassword" class="submit_forgotPassword">Forgot your
                password?</a>
        </p>
        <p class="remember">
            <input id="signin_submit" value="Sign in" tabindex="6" type="submit">

        </p>
    </form:form>

<script>
    $('#LOGIN').ajaxForm({
        target : '#body',
        success : function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            alert(responseText);
        },
        beforeSubmit : function() {
            $.blockUI({
                message : '<h1> Just a moment...</h1>'
            });
        }
    }); 
    $('.submit_forgotPassword').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); // interrupt default hyperlink behavior
        $("#LOGIN").attr("action",$(this).attr("href"));
        $("#LOGIN").submit();
    });

</script>
```

Problem is Submit the form not perform required Action

Actually my code has Two Action 1. `submit` 2. `Forgot Password`?

1.First time we give correct values and click Submit it's working perfectly..

2.Second time(after click logout) we give emailid and click `forgot Password?` link email will send to given email id it is also working perfectly...Now problem came...

3.3rd time when we give correct values and click Submit email sending to given email(it is working like 2nd step)...

Why it is working like this i'm specified every click handler form...

When ever click `forgot password?` link every time mail sending when we give correct values also ...

give me suggestion...

Comment: `$("#LOGIN").submit();` works exactly the same as a `input type="submit"`. Thus it sends the whole form to the form's action.

Comment: yes.. i'm sending form using hiperlink.. When hiperlink click this funcion executed...i'm write?

Comment: You have changed the action url here:    $("#LOGIN").attr("action",$(this).attr("href")); I think that is the reson it posts the third time to forgot password action

Comment: When we remove  $("#LOGIN").submit(); forgot password? link not working.. i think this is submit the forgotpassword? Action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing form action to "forgot password" link while clicking "forgot password" button. We have to revert the form action to "submit" link otherwise "submit" button will post post to "forgot password" link.

```
<script>

    $('#LOGIN').ajaxForm({
        target : '#body',
        success : function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            alert(responseText);
        },
        beforeSubmit : function() {
            $.blockUI({
                message : '<h1> Just a moment...</h1>'
            });
        }
    }); 
    $('.submit_forgotPassword').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); // interrupt default hyperlink behavior
        //Save original form submit link before changinf it to forgot password link
        var submitBtnLink = $("#LOGIN").attr("action");
        $("#LOGIN").attr("action",$(this).attr("href"));
        $("#LOGIN").submit();
       //Revert form action to submit link after submitting forgot password
       $("#LOGIN").attr("action",submitBtnLink);
    });

</script>
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to NOT use the login form action as the forgot password handler.

```
$("#LOGIN").attr("action",$(this).attr("href"));
        $("#LOGIN").submit();
```

If you have a forgot password page, why not simply redirect to that page and handle the request from there?

Confusion may be that your using ajaxForm plugin which suggests to use this to submit the form:

```
// attach handler to form's submit event 
$('#myFormId').submit(function() { 
    // submit the form 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(); 
    // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
    return false; 
});
```

I would treat the reset password as a seperate request and grab any paramters you wish to use like username as data like so:

```
var queryString = $('#myFormId').formSerialize();
```

This depends on what you want to achieve. Can you explain why your submitting the form with the reset password action?

Using JSP doesn't make any difference I can see.

Answer (score 1):

You have changed the submit Url here:

```
$('.submit_forgotPassword').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); // interrupt default hyperlink behavior
        $("#LOGIN").attr("action",$(this).attr("href"));
        $("#LOGIN").submit();
    });
```

So you will need to reset the url on submit click:

```
 $('#signin_submit').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); // interrupt default hyperlink behavior
        $("#LOGIN").attr("action","login/processLogin");
        $("#LOGIN").submit();
    });
```